# To what legal extent can parents prevent children from masturbating?

Tags: united-states, children, parental-rights

There was a meme circulating around of an [Amazon review](https://pics.me.me/keeps-my-son-from-sinning-october-20-2015-by-james-3355121.png) of a chastity belt (Be warned, there's a chastity belt in the image). It essentially is a mother describing her absolute joy that her son is no longer "sinning" at night thanks to a chastity belt.

Whether this is actually real, morally acceptable, socially acceptable or good parenting is another question. But I'm curious on whether this is legal and if religion is a legal justification of such actions.

I feel that if any minor told me that their mother puts a chastity belt on them I'd be morally obligated to call CPS.

**To what legal extent can parents prevent children from masturbating and are religious reasons legal justifications for such actions?**

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about forbidding masturbation or putting their child in a chastity belt?  Because the latter probably constitutes sexual abuse regardless of the reasoning behind use, while I could see the former being legislated either way.

Comment: I'm asking "to what legal extent can parents prevent children from masturbating?" and "if religion is legal justification of such actions."

Comment: OK, if you don't mind please [edit](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/31350/edit) your question to make that clear at the end.

Comment: While I agree with you, the laws and interpretations are likely to vary from state to state.  My uninformed guess would be that there aren't likely to be laws specifically about chastity belts, so it would be a judgment all by Child Protective Services.

Comment: @DavidThornley I made an educated guess that a chastity belt would be considered a sexual toy, like if a parent was using a dildo on their child.

Comment: The device appears to be this one: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stainless-Steel-Massage-Lock-Comfortable/dp/B07RPDDPNG/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8. It is sold as a sex toy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To what legal extent can parents prevent children from masturbating
>   and are religious reasons legal justifications for such actions?

One of the main restrictions on parental authority is a prohibition on engaging in child abuse or neglect. But, in most cases, this either isn't defined at all, or is defined only in the most general terms (in the same way culpability for an accident depends upon "negligence" which is also only vaguely defined).

So, somebody would have to decide if that conduct constitutes abuse or neglect of a child (realistically, this fact pattern would involve the issue of abuse, rather than neglect), and while religious reasons can justify some conduct that might otherwise be considered abusive because it caused harm for no justifiable reason, ultimately, the interest of the state in preventing the abuse of children outweighs freedom of religion and could give rise to criminal child abuse charges and/or termination of parental rights.

Whether or not a chastity belt would constitute abuse would depend upon the judgment of the relevant CPS official, a prosecuting attorney and a trial judge (possibly subject to appellate judge review), in light of common sense and community standards. There is no hard and fast rule, and the question might be resolved in different ways in different times and in different places.

Comment: Yes, you may expect two completely divergent answers to that question depending on where in the US it is answered. West Coast, almost certainly moderates to it being more akin to abuse, Through the bible belt "It don't go near far enough."

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Often different judges in the same courthouse would resolve those questions differently in practice despite applying a verbatim the same legal standard.

Answer (score -6):

> To what legal extent can parents prevent children from masturbating and are religious reasons legal justifications for such actions?

This would depend on the Jurisdiction in question

- making masturbation illegal by law

If such a law does not exist:

- then the parents have **no legal right** to prevent their children from masturbating

In most societies (to which I believe the United States is one) there is a **strict** division between Church and State and a monopoly of the State exists to **enforce** the laws of the State

- so any rules of a Church apply only to an individual of that Church who **voluntary** submits themselves to these rules

  - Church rules to not have the force of law in a juristic sense
- an individual citizen does **not** have the right to inforce any law upon another citizen

  - whereby a minor is considered to be a citizen

    - even though they are not always considered reponsible for there actions

If such a law does exist:

- implementation instructions will exist on

  - how it is to be inforced and by whom

Since I am more familiar with European laws

- I haven't the faintest clue on what these implementation details would entail

Comment: "If such a law does not exist: then the parents have no legal right to prevent their children from" - watching TV all night? Eating two pounds of candy? Going outside in winter without a coat? Swearing? The fact is, parents do have the right to prevent their children from doing all manner of things which are legal.

Comment: @DM The list of other things are not part of the question thus off topic. Please, when quoting use the whole qoute so that the quote remains in context.

Comment: So you're saying this one thing is special, and legally distinct from my examples?

Comment: @DM The answer states that when no law exsits, there is no **legal extent can parents prevent children from masturbating**

Comment: I have no idea what the random bullet points are meant to do, and they make this answer unreadable in any sensible way.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I'm trying to figure out whether you think it's a general principle that parents cannot tell their children to not do something if that something is legal, or whether you think parents cannot tell their children to not do this one particular thing. Because you didn't give any reason why this one thing is different.

Comment: @DM Sorry, but that is outside the scope of the question and answer.

Comment: @DM No, your extra question uses 'tell' ; the OP question asks 'legal means to prevent'. Those are 2 different matters.

Comment: Whatever. Do you claim that parents have no legal right to prevent their children from performing any legal act, or do you claim that this is legally special? And what is the basis for your claim? Do you have any law, precedent, Latin phrase, or anything at all besides your say-so?

Comment: @DM **nullum crimen, nulla poena sine lege scripta, praevia, certa et stricta**

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem now. You're interpreting "legal means" to mean using the law to prevent the action, while I'm interpreting "legal means" to mean "means which are not illegal".

Comment: @DM I understood the question of the OP as meaning: Would I (as parent) be supported by the law if I force my child to wear this Chastity Belt to prevent him from (private) masturbation. I believe the answer is no, because 1) private masturbation is not forbidden 2) if it was, it could only be enforced by the state and not by a 3rd party.

Comment: @DM I have added the word *private*, since North Carolina law states that *public* M and when contained in images or a part of the act of prostitution is forbidden.  That is the nearest exsisting law that I could find.

Comment: "1) private masturbation is not forbidden 2) if it was, it could only be enforced by the state and not by a 3rd party." Without giving a basis for why this case is an exception, you are basically saying that the general rule is, if some action isn't illegal, then no-one is legally allowed to forbid someone from doing that action. @DM then shows examples were legal actions are legally forbidden by parents when setting rules for their children. Given that this question deals with children, it seems that same principle would apply. You give no reason for why it doesn't apply here.